# Meteor reloads endlessly after re-deployment on server with appcache

Tags: android, meteor, html5-appcache

My Meteor app runs fine but after doing some changes and redeployment.

In fiefox there is an endless reloading
in android it seems that no connection is possible after updating the app (also endless reloading).

I tried to set the [DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3698) in the node configuration but it did not help. On my test-system the app is running beyond a NGINX server.

Cleaning the appcache helped for firefox (i am using AppCache plugin) and cleaning the app's data on android helped also.

Did this occur for anyone else? How can we solve this?

Thank you.

=== UPDATE:
In Chrome the following exception is visible:

```
Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest http://xxxxxx/app.manifest
list:1 Application Cache Checking event
list:1 Application Cache NoUpdate event
list:1 Application Cache Checking event
list:1 Application Cache NoUpdate event
Uncaught Error: Two migrations in progress?
```

### ....

=== UPDATE 2:

After investigating the issue, i came across a lot of similar issues regarding the endless reload and appcache on meteor:

- [Meteor infinite redirect instead of render 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788321/meteor-infinite-redirect-instead-of-render-404)
- https://meteor.hackpad.com/Hot-Code-Push-design-notes-9o22fy6gruu
- https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2261
- [Meteor infinite redirect instead of render 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788321/meteor-infinite-redirect-instead-of-render-404/27790687#27790687)
- https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4722

=== UPDATE 3:

this is a current log:

```html
Application Cache Checking event
Checking for manifest
Application Cache NoUpdate event
No cache updates
Navigated to http://xxxxxxx/
Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest http://xxxxxxx/app.manifest
Application Cache Checking event

//... and so on
```

Connecting the Android-Device and debugging with Chrome it says

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

after updating.

After uninstalling appcache package, everything works fine but the app must be available offline.

This is a very annoying bug in Meteor AppCache package. Does anyone know a solution to this?

==== update

we tried:

1. remove all notFoundTemplates:
2. add at LAST rule the solution described at: https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1202
3. clean your appcache and the re-deployment will work on the second deployment after the cache was cleaned

on the deployment next to the second, the error was present again :/

===== update end

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but if you are using nginx+ passenger setup, try removing meteor_runtime_config.js from cache config.
The following worked for me
eg config:

```
location /meteor_runtime_config.js {
   expires -1;
}
```