# Default route for iron router

Tags: angularjs, meteor, iron-router

I am new to iron router and looking for a route equivalent of angular ui.router 'otherwise'. I was not able to find it in the documentation. What I need is, if I define the routes as:

```
Router.route('/', function(){
        this.render('home');
});

Router.route('/signin', function(){
        this.render('signin');
});
```

If anyone types a url other that '/' or '/signin' it should be redirected to default '/' url. Something which is done by

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/'); in angular.
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788321/meteor-infinite-redirect-instead-of-render-404/27790687#27790687

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a route that match all routes except the defined ones.
Check this post: https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-do-i-redirect-all-non-existent-routes-in-iron-router/8556